# Split an XML-Node? Possibly in R

Tags: r, xml, xslt

I need to transform some XML into a different kind of XML but I don’t get it right. If possible, I would like to achieve this in R because further processing is done there anyway.

This is the XML I have:

```
<sp_list date="mm-dd-YYYY" no="XX" session="1">
  <sp_proceedings>
      <statement id="XYZ">
        <p class="speaker"><speaker id="ABC"><name>John Doe</name></speaker>John Doe:</p>
        <p>Some words of wisdom.</p>
        <name>Master of Ceremonies:</name>
        <p>Thank you. Next Speaker...</p>
      </statement>
  </sp_proceedings>
</sp_list>
```

As you can see, within the "statement"-node, there are two speakers: The first ("John Doe") is tagged with a speaker ID. The other ("Master of Ceremonies") is part of the same statement but I would need to transform it in a way that both are represented as individual statements.

What I want to achieve right now is:

```
<sp_list date="mm-dd-YYYY" no="XX" session="1">
  <sp_proceedings>
      <statement id="XYZ">
        <p class="speaker"><speaker id="ABC"><name>John Doe</name></speaker>John Doe:</p>
        <p>Some words of wisdom.</p>
      </statement>
      <statement>
        <p class="speaker"><speaker type="Master of Ceremonies"><name>Master of Ceremonies</name></speaker>Master of Ceremonies:</p>
        <p>Thank you. Next Speaker is…</p>
      </statement>
  </sp_proceedings>
</sp_list>
```

The list of statements within the  can (and will) be much longer. I essentially want to split the statement node if there is an additional speaker, so that all speakers are within their own statement node and can be processed the same way down the line.

I assume this would be a job for XSLT but after fiddling around with it for a while, I don’t get the hang of it and I am running out of things to google. I tried to simply replace the -Node of the second speaker with the according XML tags (essentially inserting `</statement><statement><p class="speaker"><speaker type="Master of Ceremonies">` instead of the name tag) but this crashes the XML-processing later on because of mismatching tags.

What would be a way to start? Is XSLT the way to go here and how would I start writing such a thing? I mean, I read a lot about what it does but I don’t seem to use the correct vocabulary to proceed. I think that it would be a useful tool to master, as soon as I find a way in. Any suggestions welcome. As written before: A R-Only solution would be great but I am willing to process the XML with the command line (unix) or whatever suits the task best.

Thank you so much!

Edit:

After the very helpful answer of @Parfait, I became aware that the number of paragraphs per speaker differs rather randomly. There could be one paragraph or 10 or 15. So I change the example as follows:

```
<sp_list date="mm-dd-YYYY" no="XX" session="1">
  <sp_proceedings>
      <statement id="XYZ">
        <p class="speaker"><speaker id="ABC"><name>John Doe</name></speaker>John Doe:</p>
        <p>Some words of wisdom.</p>
        <p>Some more words.</p>
        <p>And even more words.</p>
        <p>There are so many words.</p>
        <name>Master of Ceremonies:</name>
        <p>Thank you. Next Speaker...</p>
      </statement>
  </sp_proceedings>
</sp_list>
```

I assume I would have to determine the number of

-nodes until the -tag occurs?

Comment: Would it be correct to assume that every statement, except the first one, is given as a pair of `name` and `p` elements? Also, are you able to use an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Comment: R has a dedicated library `xslt` for XSLT 1.0 scripts but can also run command line of external .exe processors using `system()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to get the desired output is differentiating the first result from the following ones like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

      <!-- Identity template -->
      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="statement">
        <xsl:for-each select="p[not(@class)]">
          <statement>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="../@id|../p[1]" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="spk" select="translate(preceding-sibling::name[1],':','')" />
                    <p class="{preceding-sibling::p[@class]/@class}">
                    <speaker type="{$spk}"><name><xsl:value-of select="$spk" /></name></speaker><xsl:value-of select="concat($spk,':')" /></p>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
          </statement>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Its output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sp_list date="mm-dd-YYYY" no="XX" session="1">
    <sp_proceedings>
        <statement id="XYZ">
            <p class="speaker">
                <speaker id="ABC">
                    <name>John Doe</name>
                </speaker>
            John Doe:</p>
            <p>Some words of wisdom.</p>
        </statement>
        <statement>
            <p class="speaker">
                <speaker type="Master of Ceremonies">
                    <name>Master of Ceremonies</name>
                </speaker>
            Master of Ceremonies:</p>
            <p>Thank you. Next Speaker...</p>
        </statement>
    </sp_proceedings>
</sp_list>
```

All of the following `<p>` - `<name>` pairs from the input will be output like the second `<statement>` output.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a template and call it inside a `for-each` for each *name* and *p* pairing:

**XSLT** *(save as an .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/sp_list/sp_proceedings">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="statement"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="statement">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="p[count(preceding-sibling::name) = 0]"/>
     </xsl:copy>
     <xsl:for-each select="name">
          <p class="speaker">
            <speaker type="{.}">
                <name><xsl:value-of select="."/></name>
            </speaker>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ':')"/>
          </p>
          <xsl:variable name="name_idx" select="count(preceding-sibling::name)+1"/>

          <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::p[count(preceding-sibling::name)
                                                      = $name_idx]">
              <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each>        
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38ZL/2) *(extended input for demonstration)*

**R**

```
library(xml2)
library(xslt)

doc <- read_xml("Input.xml", package = "xslt")
style <- read_xml("Script.xsl", package = "xslt")

new_xml <- xml_xslt(doc, style)   
write_xml(new_xml, "Output.xml")
```

Comment: Thank you, I think, I am getting the idea of it now. What makes me wonder though is the line <xsl:copy-of select="p[position() &lt; 3]"/>. If I add a few more paragraphs to the statement (if I have <p>Some words of wisdom.</p> 4 times for example), I'll won't capture these with the &lt; 3 expression, right? Is there a way to link the number (3 in this case) of paragraphs selected to the actual position of the <name> node if I don't know how many paragraphs there are? Sorry if I wasn't clear about this uncertainty earlier. And thanks again, this is very helpful!

Comment: The `&lt;` is the less than `<` operator (written as an entity since this angle bracket is an XML symbol). It is meant to skip the first two *name* and *p* pairings. if you see the online demo above, I added an additional *name* and *p* to your posted sample to demonstrate this XSLT covers all pairings after first two. In fact, I add more in this [version](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38ZL/1). Please update your sample if these inputs do not match your actual.

Comment: I did change the example to make things more clear, I hope.

Comment: See update hopefully to handle any number of *p* after last *name*.